# Keeping zeros as leading digits in a kendo grid

Tags: php, mysql, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to save a transaction number where there can be zeros in beginning of the same. When I save 0055, it is displayed as 55 in the kendo grid as the grid removes the leading zeros. However, the number is saved as 0055 in DB.

Comment: Please provide your code. May be you need number formatting http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting

Comment: Thanks qisho. But I couldn't find solution in number formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type your data has, but in general, you would use a column template, e.g.:

```
template: '#= kendo.toString(UnitsInStock, "0000000.\\#\\#\\#\\#") #'
```

which means that the number will always show with 7 digits left of the decimal point (leading zeros if necessary) and 4 or less on the right.

([demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/uMUca))

Comment: Thanks Lars, but there can be any number of zeros, not a fixed one. The number can 00001 or 00011 or 00111 and Kendo is removing the zeros.

Comment: All three of those will show as you said. If the number of digits is variable, then you need to calculate the length in the template.  A number is a number, it can't have leading zeros. Has nothing to do with kendo ui. It sounds like you should be working with strings.